# What's wrong with this sql statement using sqlcmd

Tags: sql, sql-server

I try to execute a script file via sqlcmd in batch file:

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -d DB-U sa -P xxx -i D:\Database\Scripts\Standard\DeleteAllJobs.sql
```

The .sql file content:

```
use [DB]

DECLARE @jobID int;
DECLARE Job_Cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT ID FROM Job;

OPEN Job_Cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM Job_Cursor INTO @jobID;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN
        EXEC dbo.spDeleteJobHard @jobID;
        FETCH NEXT FROM Job_Cursor INTO @jobID;
   END;
CLOSE Job_Cursor;
DEALLOCATE Job_Cursor;
```

When I execute this on commandline I get the error:
The Syntax of the command is incorrect.
Executing this command in SMSS works fine.
Used SQLServer is 2008 R2.

Any ideas what is wrong with this statement?

Comment: Can you try with instance name? sqlcmd -S yourpcname\instancename ...

Comment: Without being too specific, what types of characters are there in your password?

Comment: The connection can be established, because i get the response that the database context is changed to "DB". So the connection string seems to be ok.

Comment: -d DB-U  here between DB and -U no space, can you try with space?

Comment: It works now, but it was an error in another line in the batch file which causes the above output. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Please add an answer and mark it as the answer so that this doesn't appear in the list of unanswered questions.